# TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i tried to make a function with discord.js that firstly connects to the voice i am in, but every tutorial i looked in, has message.member.voice.channel which for my compiler says it is undefined.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "join",
    async execute(client, msg, args){
        try{
            const connection = await msg.member.voice.channel.join();
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your command handler pass in the arguments in the proper order? `(client, msg, args)`

Comment: Yes, its not the first function i made. All the other ones work.

Comment: So i somehow  made it work, but still idk why the other one doesnt work. I started to think it is outdated but it is in the discord.js documentation so idk.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other one"?

Comment: const connection = message.member.voice.channel.join();

Comment: I started working on a broadcast and it said that client.voice.createBroadcast() is not a function. Idk what to do.

Comment: I'd recommend you create a separate question for that then, considering this issue is resolved.